# .NET Razor in Sitefinity - Check if related fields exist in widget

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sitefinity

**Edit for clarity:** In Sitefinity (Feather) using related data I would like to only display a wrapping HTML tag or header/footer around the for each only if a related item exists - otherwise hide that HTML.

**Original Question:**

I'm building a site in Sitefinity and have a module with related items. Using Razor, I want to see if there are any related items and then show content around my foreach but what I'm trying results in an error.

Here's what I have tried:

```
@if(Model.Item.Fields.RelatedPeople){
    <ul class="list">

    @foreach (var relatedItem in Model.Item.Fields.RelatedPeople){
        <li>@relatedItem.Title</li>
    }

    </ul>
}
```

I'm not very savvy on Razor syntax - any help would be appreciated!

Here's the error message:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Models.ItemViewModel[]' to 'bool'
```

Comment: show your error please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Discovered that you need to use .Length instead of .Count() for this:

```
@if(Model.Item.Fields.RelatedPeople.Length > 0){
    <ul class="list">
        @foreach (var relatedItem in Model.Item.Fields.RelatedPeople){
            <li>@relatedItem.Title</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Works! My ul isn't rendered unless there are more than <strike>one</strike> **zero** "RelatedPeople"

Comment: Your `<ul>` isn't rendered unless there are more than zero "RelatedPeople".

Comment: @RJCuthbertson My mistake!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but i gess it should be like this:

```
@if(Model.Item.Fields.RelatedPeople != null
     && Model.Item.Fields.RelatedPeople.Count() > 0){
    <ul class="list">

    @foreach (var relatedItem in Model.Item.Fields.RelatedPeople){
        <li>@relatedItem.Title</li>
    }

    </ul>
}
```

It's strange that you use `RelatedPeople` property in `if` construction and in `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the error and forgot to mention I had tried both != null and .Count() > 0. I'm using my foreach as my repeater but I don't wan't to show my wrapping elements unless those exist. I don't know if there is a better way (like "HeaderTemplate") that I could implement instead.

Comment: @StuFu but your error is talking that you use array instead of bool value in your if statement.

Comment: This should be the answer. He accepted his own answer two days after you provided this solution (which is correct). You can use .Count() on an array... provided you have the `System.Linq` namespace imported.

Comment: @StuFu please explain the logical difference between https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c17z56h7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx ...

Comment: @StuFu the two are functionally equivalent. You said "this will not work with checking Related Data in Sitefinity Feather and is not correct" when it most certainly is correct, and credit should be given to teo.